# Jenkins/JAR link for Eclipse EEF 1.5.2

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-emf

Currently, Eclipse EEF Runtime plugin is 1.5.1 released and 1.5.2 is in master branch.

See: [EEF Runtime](https://github.com/eclipse/eef/tree/master/plugins/org.eclipse.emf.eef.runtime)

I'm unable to find 1.5.2 JAR files anywhere as I'm guessing it's not released yet. So, is there any Jenkins link available where EEF is built regularly, so that I can take the JAR file from there?

Answer (score 0):

It seems releases are [here](https://www.eclipse.org/eef/#/download). Note how org.eclipse.emf.eef is different from org.eclipse.eef. If you have code that depends on EEF you probably want to study the implications of updating to recent versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the latest build of the 1.5.x branch on [this update site](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emft/eef/updates/milestones/1.5/S201707060903/). EEF 1.5.x is now deprecated and you should have a look at EEF 1.6.x and more (we are now on EEF 2.0.x).

[The new version](https://www.eclipse.org/eef/#/) has changed its namespace from org.eclipse.emf.eef to org.eclipse.eef to prevent any conflicts (you can install both at once).

You can see the new feature of EEF with the Sirius support for Properties View in [this presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/melbats/eclipsecon-france-2016-sirius-40-let-me-sirius-that-for-you) or even [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6G4uPThR4Ms&t=2s) (slides [here](https://www.slideshare.net/melbats/eclipsecon-france-2017-all-about-ux-in-sirius)).